# How to detect when Facebook share has been cancelled from UIActivityViewController setCompletionWithItemsHandler

Tags: ios, facebook, ios8, uiactivityviewcontroller

The completion handler seems to work correctly for all the other share types (Twitter, Mail) but for Facebook, the complete BOOL is YES even when you cancel the share (having first tapped the Facebook icon).

```
UIActivityViewController *shareActivity = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[title, url] applicationActivities:nil];
[shareActivity setCompletionWithItemsHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL complete, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError) {
                if (complete) { //Facebook share is always YES }];
```

Any suggestions?

iOS 8.3, Facebook App installed.

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: When you select share are you context switching to the Facebook application? What occurs when you do not have the application installed?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this problem?